# Unable to set image for bxSlider 'next/prev' controls

Tags: jquery, html, css, bxslider

**Question Background:**

I'm using bxSlider to implement a gallery in my site as shown:

[image]

**The Issue:**

I'm trying to set the `prev` and `next` controls to the prev and next arrows supplied in the controls.png image file with the bxSlider project as shown:

[image]

Currently I'm not able to set these images and the prev and next controls of my image are just `< >`, as shown (**please note:** these can be seen in the gallery picture at the top of this question):

[image]

**The code:**

HTML markup for the bxSlider gallery:

```
  <div class="bxslider-controls">
            <span id="bx-prev4"><a class="bx-next"></a></span>
            <span id="bx-next4"><a class="bx-prev"></a></span>
        </div>
        <ul class="bxslider" id="bx4">
            <li>
                <img src="~/Images/wf1.jpg" alt="...">
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="~/Images/wf2.jpg" alt="...">
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="~/Images/wf3.jpg" alt="...">
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="~/Images/wf4.jpg" alt="...">
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Currently I've changed the background image url to the `controls.png` file (stored in the Images folder on my site) on the `.bx-prev` and `.bx-prev` CSS styling in the  `bxSlider.css` class:

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
   left: 10px;
   background: url(~/Images/controls.png) no-repeat 0 -32px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next {
   right: 10px;
   background: url(~/Images/controls.png) no-repeat -43px -32px;
}
```

The following JQuery is used to control the bxSlider gallery images, not the `nextText` and `prevText` properties:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#bx4').bxSlider({
        hideControlOnEnd: true,
        minSlides: 4,
        maxSlides: 4,
        slideWidth: 360,
        slideMargin: 10,
        pager: false,
        nextSelector: '#bx-next4',
        prevSelector: '#bx-prev4',
        nextText: '>',
        prevText: '<',

     });
   });
```

Any help in working out why I cant apply the images in `controls.png` to the prev and next  tags in the HTML would be great.

**UPDATE:**

New CSS styling named `anchors`:

```
.anchors{
    display:inline-block;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
```

Applied to the  tags:

```
<div class="bxslider-controls">
   <span id="bx-prev4"><a class="bx-next anchors"></a></span>
   <span id="bx-next4"><a class="bx-prev anchors"></a></span>
</div>
```

I've removed the ~ from the Image path:

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
    left: 10px;
    background: url(/Images/controls.png) no-repeat 0 -32px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next {
    right: 10px;
    background: url(/Images/controls.png) no-repeat -43px -32px;
}
```

Output now:

[image]

As can be seen the inline spacing has taken affect but still the images do not show.

Comment: Do the control anchors take up space? Since you are applying a BG image to an anchor, you need to set the anchor to a block or inline block element and give it a width and height. Otherwise with no content, it's 0 px tall and wide and you won't see it's bg.,

Comment: Also, is there other CSS acting on those elements? If so where and what are the styles applied to it.

Comment: Leeish is correct, you are using spans for links, that are inline elements by default. you need to explicitly set them as "inline-block" or "block" level elements and set width/height and/or padding on them so the background image can display.

Comment: @Leeish Please see the edited section of my question with the new css. I have created a new custom CSS style class called .anchors. This set the display element to inline block and I gave a width of height of 50px. I also changed the way the path was being rendered to the image. The issue is still present though.

Comment: @SeanThompson Thanks for your reply. I've taken what you and Leeish have said and applied a new pirce of styling on the <a> tags to set the display element and size of the anchors.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-prev {
    left: 10px;
    width: 32px; 
    height: 32px;
    background: url(~/Images/controls.png) no-repeat 0 -32px;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-next {
    right: 10px;
    width: 32px; 
    height: 32px;
    background: url(~/Images/controls.png) no-repeat -43px -32px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have applied your CSS and there was no change the images do not show.

Comment: See my above comment. Is there other CSS acting on those elements and if so can you paste that. Somewhere in the bx css files, the same items have some CSS applied. Also, I've never seen `~` in an image path in CSS. Is that valid? Typically I've only use `/` and `../` for relative paths.

Comment: I have applied go your first comment and updated my question to show the changes I've applied

Comment: Can you confirm `~` is valid when referencing images in CSS? I've never seen that before.

Comment: in my IDE (Visual Studio) it was showing the path to the images folder when I used the ~. I have now removed it (as shown in the update section). Issue still persists though.

Comment: In all honesty unless I can see the code live it's hard to tell. I feel like the bx css is overriding yours but I can't tell. Can you inspect the element with Firebug and see the image is being applied and not overwritten and in fact the URL given resolves in at a valid image? It could also be overwritten with JS. so without being able to see the page live I really can't tell/

Comment: Also did you read the FAQ for that product? http://bxslider.com/faqs It cover these arrow images.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with bxslider on rails and it's worked like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#bx4').bxSlider({
        hideControlOnEnd: true,
        minSlides: 4,
        maxSlides: 4,
        slideWidth: 360,
        slideMargin: 10,
        pager: false,

     });
   });
```

and css:

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-next {
  right: 10px;
  background: image-url('controls.png') no-repeat -43px -32px;
}
```